# what is an `AVFocusProxyView` in tvOS? Getting a weird focus issue

Tags: swift, xcode, tvos, uifocusguide

what is an `AVFocusProxyView` ? When we show the `AVContentProposal` on top of a full screen player, `AVFocusProxyView` is hiding the accept/reject button . I am not able to move focus when this happens. And I am getting the following error on the UIFocusDebugger console :

[image]

This is the error:

> - Issue: The item is being visually occluded by the following items: AVFocusProxyView 0x149e22600

How to fix this? There is no documentation as well as google results about `AVFocusProxyView`.

[image]
AVFocusProxyView appears over the top of every button/views.

### Solution for the focus issue that we face because of `AVFocusProxyView`.

We were unable to move the focus around because of the `AVFocusProxyView` overlay on top of the `AVContentProposal`. The fix was to add `UIFocusGuide`:

```
view.addFocusGuide(anchorView: acceptButton, heading: .left   , sideSize: 80, targetFocus: rejectButton)
view.addFocusGuide(anchorView: rejectButton, heading: .right  , sideSize: 80, targetFocus: acceptButton)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hidding the AVFocusProxyView fixed the issue for me.
iterate through the subview and hide the AVFocusProxyView fixed the issue